# R - Executing a function columnwise across two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, xts

I have two timeseries matrices:
A: consists of 500 columns holding the returns of the S&P constituents
B: consisting of one column, holding the return of the index (S&P500)

I would like to execute this function:

```
beta_function <- function(stock, index1)  cov(stock, index1)/var(index1)
```

R should apply it in a 12-month window.

To sum it up:
I want that R executes the function that the beta for every stock is calculated for every 12-month-window per stock.

I tried:
- repeating the values of the S&P500 index returns 500 times, to achieve a matrix with the same dimensions as the stock return matrix.

If I apply my function via

```
apply.rolling(c(returns_constituents, returns_index), 
                   width = 12, by = 12, FUN = beta_function)
```

it returns the error:

```
 Error in is.data.frame(y) : argument "index1" is missing, with no default
```

Even assigning previous to executing the `apply.rolling` function

```
index1 <- returns_index
```

did not solve my problem.

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much.

Example:

```
stock <- matrix(c(runif(n = 84000, min = -1, max = 1)), ncol = 500, nrow = 168)
index1 <- matrix(c(runif(n = 168, min = -1, max = 1)), ncol = 1, nrow = 168)
```

My try was to "extend" the index:

```
index1_ext <- matrix(c(runif(n = 8400, min = -1, max = 1)), ncol = 500, nrow = 168)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data, not just code, should be minimal so we have cut the data down making it 15x2 (see Note at end).  Also we made it reproducible by using `set.seed` and used 3 instead of 12.

The key here is to iterate over the index rather than over the data. No packages are used.

```
sq <- seq_along(index1)
bfun <- function(ix) apply(stock[ix, ], 2, beta_function, index1[ix])
t(sapply(split(sq, (sq - 1) %/% 3), bfun))
```

giving:

```
        [,1]       [,2]
0  0.1369903  2.5808410
1 -0.2041141 -0.7671860
2 -0.4868275 -0.1372993
3 -1.5786697 -0.6059759
4  2.1902241  1.3766969
```

### Note

```
set.seed(123)
stock <- matrix(c(runif(n = 30, min = -1, max = 1)), ncol = 2, nrow = 15)
index1 <- matrix(c(runif(n = 15, min = -1, max = 1)), ncol = 1, nrow = 15)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you explain me why the first two rows contain NAs?  In the end I should have 14 beta values (one per each window) and this for every company (column). How can I take this into account?

Comment: OK. Have revised.  Also, now it uses 15x2 in the example.